# Does MySQL can handle 10 Billions rows of data which has 10-12 columns ?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need help and i'm confused whether MySQL can handle 10 Billion rows with 10-12 columns of data or should i have to look for other Opensource databases like PostGreSQL etc.

Please let me know.

Comment: You should tell us what is your business need for this many rows.  It could be, for example, that NoSQL is a better fit.

Comment: Any enterprise database can scale according to server resources.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to dba.

Comment: I need to create a workflow so that every time i run a macro using VBA it should pick the some certain percentage of data (say about 1 to 2 lakhs) to paste it in Excel from the Billions rows in database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, MySQL can handle 10 billion rows. When you define ids on the largest tables, use a `bigint`.

Of course, whether performance is good or not depends on your queries.  For basic inserts, updates, deletes, and selects using an index, performance should be okay -- assuming you have enough memory. You might also want to be partitioning your tables.

Comment: Thanks Gordon i'll use bigint instead of int. At present i'm using MySQL for handling few million of data, i was worried whether MySQL can handle Billions of data if it handles will there be any performance lag